# How to make OpenGL render utilize maximum of CPU power?

Tags: rendering, opengl

I am rendering `Scene` strip from **VSE** in **OpenGL** mode and only 1 of 16 threads (AMD Ryzen 1700) is fully loaded, others are just around 5-10%. Overall CPU usage is about 15-20%.

Firstly I thought low perfomance could be caused by the fact that **VSE** is not multithreaded. But tested it with **Cycles** `Scene` strip and everything is fine - all threads are busy.

Need to speed up this **OpenGL** thing somehow, preferably without instancing of Blender app itself.

Comment: VSE does not support multithreading. It's completely independent from any of the render engines because its only purpose is to edit videos composed of already rendered images (or otherwise acquired images).

Comment: @metaphor_set, VSE doesn't support multithreading on image/movie sequence, NOT `Scene` strips. I've tested Cycles `scene` strip and it works as like normal render, but not OpenGL.